# hover state of :before shape in unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list. and I've created a square shape as a before shape. But I'm trying to change it color while hovering the text of that `<li>` no results so far, any suggestions? thanks!

HTML

```
<nav class="menu-vertical">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">REVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MAGAZINE</a></li>
            <li><a href="">PODCAST</a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>
```

CSS

```
.menu-vertical ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:  20px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu-vertical ul li {
list-style: none;
}

.menu-vertical ul li:before {
content:"";
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color: fuchsia;
position: absolute;
margin-top:6px;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: text-decoration 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

.menu-vertical ul li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-vertical ul li a:hover {
color: #36b3d5;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I was trying to make for this:

`.menu-vertical ul li:before a:hover` but didn't work:(

Comment: Your solution would style the `a`nchor tag, not the `li:before`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
.menu-vertical ul li:hover:before { background-color: red; }
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysfze040/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another CSS rule:

```
.menu-vertical ul li:hover:before {
    background-color: #36b3d5;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU BOTH:D @VincentG and PaulEduardStanciu